# C# socket problem with receiving data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, timeout

I'm currently writing a test program for an network attached mircocontroller which controls a led light.

When I'm trying to receive an answer from the remote host the whole procedure gets stuck in the socket.receive function.

I'm sending a few bytes of data using a socket to the remote host. Then I listen for incomming data. But at the point where I receive the data the program just stops without an exception or anything.

Send-Function :

```
    public void Send(Command cmd)
    {
        switch (cmd.command)
        {
            case CommandType.SetAll:
                send_data(SET_COLOR_ALL, cmd.data, 3);
                break;
            case CommandType.SetRed:
                send_data(SET_COLOR_RED, cmd.data, 1);
                break;
            case CommandType.SetGreen:
                send_data(SET_COLOR_GREEN, cmd.data, 1);
                break;
            case CommandType.SetBlue:
                send_data(SET_COLOR_BLUE, cmd.data, 1);
                break;
            case CommandType.GetColor:
                Debug.WriteLine("Sending request...");
                send_data(GET_COLOR, cmd.data, 0);
                read_data(); //here it gets stuck !
                break;
        }
        m_socket.Disconnect(true);
    }
```

Extract from read_data()

```
    private void read_data()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Called read_data()");
        byte[] t_buffer = new byte[4];
        try
        {
            if(!m_socket.Connected)
                m_socket.Listen(10000);
            sock_receive(m_socket, ref t_buffer, 0, t_buffer.Length, 10000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
            throw ex; 
        }
        finally { // do some stuff here }
   }
```

And here the sock_receive function where everything gets stuck :

```
    public static void sock_receive(Socket socket,ref byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
    {
        int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        int received = 0;  // how many bytes is already received
        do
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("In Loop..");
            if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
                throw new Exception("Timeout.");
            try
            {
                //here it gets stuck !
                received += socket.Receive(buffer, offset + received, size - received, SocketFlags.None); 
                Debug.WriteLine("Byte arrived, received : " + received.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Socket exception !");
                if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                    ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                    ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                {
                    // socket buffer is probably empty, wait and try again
                    Thread.Sleep(30);
                }
                else
                    throw ex;  // any serious error occurr
            }
        } while (received < size);
    }
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Greetings

n0pt3x

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that m_socket is a server socket which listens for connections? Naturally, you can't receive data from it, you have to call Accept() first, and read from the socket that it returns.

Comment: yes I tried this but that causes the error "You have to call the Listen-method before executing this procedure" (free translation from german exception). And yes, I called the Listen() method for the Accept() client.

Comment: Let's start from the beginning: who listens and who connects, the microcontroller or your app?

Comment: my app connects to the microcontroller and sends data. the microcontroller is listening. when it receives the command (GET_COLOR) it sends data back to the client (the app). The app then should receive the data and proceed it.

Comment: Okay, in that case, no need to call listen, the socket should be connected after you call Connect() to it and sent the data. Can you confirm that the microcontroller receives the data? If you want your application not to freeze while waiting, read about the Socket.Select() method. It will tell you if there's any incoming data, and if there isn't, it will return after a specified amount of time.

Comment: Yes the microntroller receives the data and also sends data back. But receiving the data from within the application doesn't work. I didn't try with m_socket.Accept() but I will do so now. What do you mean with the Select() method ? As far as I see there isn't such a method.